# Загрузка uniform структур в фрагментный шейдер glsl

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Есть фрагментный шейдер со структурами внутри
Кусочек glsl:

```
#version 330
```

const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 3;

in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec3 normal0;
in vec3 worldPos0;

out vec4 fragColor;

struct BaseLight
{
  vec3  color;
  float ambientIntensity;
  float diffuseIntensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
  BaseLight base;
  vec3 direction;
};

struct Attenuation
{
  float constant;
  float linear;
  float expVar;
};

struct PointLight
{
  BaseLight     base;
  vec3          position;
  Attenuation   atten;
};

uniform int                 gNumPointLights;
uniform PointLight          gPointLights [ MAX_POINT_LIGHTS ];
uniform DirectionalLight    gDirectionalLight;
//...

Далее в приложении (с++) я собираюсь передать данные в uniform параметры шейдера. Сразу отмечу - компиляция шейдера успешна а конвеер коректен. Естественно перед передачей данных нам нужны позиции uniform. Вот тут и проблема. Как делаю я

```
//...
m_WVPLocation         = GetUniformLocation ( "gWVP" );
  m_WorldMatrixLocation = GetUniformLocation ( "gWorld" );
  m_samplerLocation     = GetUniformLocation ( "gSampler" );
```

m_dirLightLocation.color            =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.base.color" );
  m_dirLightLocation.ambientIntensity =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.base.ambientIntensity" );
  m_dirLightLocation.diffuseIntensity =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.base.diffuseIntensity" );
  m_dirLightLocation.direction        =   GetUniformLocation ( "gDirectionalLight.direction" );

m_eyeWorldPosLocation           = GetUniformLocation ( "gEyeWorldPos" );
  m_matSpecularIntensityLocation  = GetUniformLocation ( "gMatSpecularIntensity" );
  m_matSpecularPowerLocation      = GetUniformLocation ( "gSpecularPower" );
//...

Из-за вложенности структур, не подтягиваются позиции полей вложенности 2 уровня и ниже, НО, кроме первого поля. Например для `gDirectionalLight`, я получил позицию `gDirectionalLight.base.color` и `gDirectionalLight.direction`, а `gDirectionalLight.base.ambientIntensity` и `gDirectionalLight.base.diffuseIntensity` нет((( Гугл рыл, решения не нашел. Неужели выход только в повторении кода в шейдере? Уточнение - не получаю адресов конкретно 2 атрибутов `base.ambientIntensity` и `base.diffuseIntensity` во всех объектах.
Перерыл спецификацию glsl, использую версию 3.0, вложенность структур поддерживается если структуры не анонимны:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж))) Много нервов спустя и тщательным эксперементальным путем опрелено - uniform переменные автоматической оптимезацией игнорируются компилятором шейдера. Итог - их нет, и позиций к ним соответственно. Но это не все, в полном варианте шейдера, казалось бы, все uniform активны (пример из уроков)

```
#version 330
```

const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 3;

in vec2 TexCoord0;
in vec3 Normal0;
in vec3 WorldPos0;

out vec4 FragColor;

struct BaseLight
{
    vec3 Color;
    float AmbientIntensity;
    float DiffuseIntensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
    struct BaseLight Base;
    vec3 Direction;
};

struct Attenuation
{
    float Constant;
    float Linear;
    float Exp;
};

struct PointLight
{
    struct BaseLight Base;
    vec3 Position;
    Attenuation Atten;
};

uniform int gNumPointLights;
uniform DirectionalLight gDirectionalLight;
uniform PointLight gPointLights[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform sampler2D gSampler;
uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;
uniform float gMatSpecularIntensity;
uniform float gSpecularPower;

vec4 CalcLightInternal(struct BaseLight Light, vec3 LightDirection, vec3 Normal)
{
    vec4 AmbientColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * Light.AmbientIntensity;
    float DiffuseFactor = dot(Normal, -LightDirection);

```
vec4 DiffuseColor  = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                 
vec4 SpecularColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                 

if (DiffuseFactor > 0) 
{                                                               
    DiffuseColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * Light.DiffuseIntensity * DiffuseFactor;   

    vec3 VertexToEye = normalize(gEyeWorldPos - WorldPos0);                            
    vec3 LightReflect = normalize(reflect(LightDirection, Normal));                    
    float SpecularFactor = dot(VertexToEye, LightReflect);                             
    SpecularFactor = pow(SpecularFactor, gSpecularPower);                              
    if (SpecularFactor > 0) 
    {                                                          
        SpecularColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * 
                        gMatSpecularIntensity * SpecularFactor;                        
    }                                                                                  
}                                                                                      

return (AmbientColor + DiffuseColor + SpecularColor);
```

}

vec4 CalcDirectionalLight(vec3 Normal)
{
    return CalcLightInternal(gDirectionalLight.Base, gDirectionalLight.Direction, Normal); 
}

vec4 CalcPointLight(int Index, vec3 Normal)
{
    vec3 LightDirection = WorldPos0 - gPointLights[Index].Position;
    float Distance = length(LightDirection);
    LightDirection = normalize(LightDirection);

```
vec4 Color = CalcLightInternal(gPointLights[Index].Base, LightDirection, Normal);      
float Attenuation =  gPointLights[Index].Atten.Constant +                              
                     gPointLights[Index].Atten.Linear * Distance +                     
                     gPointLights[Index].Atten.Exp * Distance * Distance;              

return Color / Attenuation;
```

}

void main()
{
    vec3 Normal = normalize(Normal0);
    vec4 TotalLight = CalcDirectionalLight(Normal);

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < gNumPointLights ; i++) {                                          
    TotalLight += CalcPointLight(i, Normal);                                           
}                                                                                      

FragColor = texture2D(gSampler, TexCoord0.xy) * TotalLight;
```

}

Долго копаясь, прикрепляем НАДЕЖНЫЙ костыль

```
//...
void main()

{

  vec3 normal = normalize( normal0 );
```

gDirectionalLight.base.color;
  gDirectionalLight.base.ambientIntensity;
  gDirectionalLight.base.diffuseIntensity;
//...
 
ИИИ, да, все заработало!!!! КАК? что опираясь на все что имеем, сделаю вывод, пока, что из третьего в стеке вызовов блока функции, *активность*, еще и вложеной передаваемой структуры - не распознана, поэтому, в главной функции я просто перечислил поля. Также стоит отметить, передавалось только первое поле структуры, видимо это связано с тем, что в параметрах вызова, мы ее передаем, целиком, ну и выходит шейдер распознал в блоке только первое поле, *активной* структуры. Запутано, но поэксперементировав с кодом - вы разберетесь. В спецификации соответствий этому не нашел - может это связано с видео-картой. На этом все)))))